# What is the name for the bank a check is written against?

Tags: banking, check, terminology

I'm drafting a contract and want it to say that payment will be made by (among other ways) checks from a US bank (not from banks in other countries).

What's the correct way to refer to the bank that a check instructs payment from?

Would "check against a United States bank" be an accurate phrase? Is "against" the right word here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use the phrase "check drawn on a United States bank."

The payer's bank in a check transaction is referred to as the *drawing bank*, and the bank that the payee gives the check to for deposit or cashing is called the *receiving bank*.